# Como assinar documentos com certificado digital?

Tags: delphi, criptografia, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Gostaria de saber como assinar documentos com certificado digital usando `Delphi` ou `Lazarus`.
Se alguém souber de algum componente, de preferencia livre, ou alguma função que eu possa usar ajudaria muito.

Comment: Que tipo de assinatura? Qual o tipo de certificado?

Answer (score 8):

Resposta retirada desse [link](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/assinando-documentos-xml-com-capicom-e.html).

**Assinando documentos XML com CAPICOM e Delphi**

A Microsoft disponibiliza para o Windows uma biblioteca com tecnologia COM para tratar a criação e manipulação de arquivos XML. A biblioteca, chamada MSXML, está atualmente na versão 6 e suporta também transformações XSLT e validação através de esquemas XSD. Em apenas uma das versões (o MSXML5), foram incluídos ainda recursos para fazer assinatura digital de XMLs.

A versão 5 foi distribuída exclusivamente com o Microsoft Office para que os desenvolvedores dessa plataforma pudessem assinar XMLs. No entanto, uma busca na internet revela que a biblioteca é amplamente utilizada fora desse contexto.

Isto é uma boa notícia para quem usa Delphi (ou outra linguagem que suporte COM) pois o MSXML5, em associação com o CAPICOM, facilita bastante a tarefa de assinar XMLs. Neste post eu mostro como realizar este processo, considerando que você já tem montado o XML que quer assinar. O quadro abaixo mostra parte do XML de uma Nota Fiscal que vou usar como exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<enviNFe versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
   <idLote>71</idLote>
   <NFe>
      <infNFe Id="NFe3508059978" versao="2.00">
         <cUF>35</cUF>
         <cNF>518005127</cNF>
         <natOp>Venda a vista</natOp>
         <mod>55</mod>
         <serie>1</serie>
         <dEmi>2012-05-06</dEmi>
         <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
      </infNFe>
   </NFe>
</enviNFe>
```

A primeira providência é importar os fontes dos ActiveX MSXML5 e CAPICOM para podermos utilizá-los no projeto Delphi. Há um resumo de como fazer essa importação [neste endereço](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/trabalhando-com-o-certificate-store-em.html); para o MSXML5, a descrição da Type Library é Microsoft XML, v5.0. Ambos os fontes gerados devem ser incluídos na cláusula uses da unit que for fazer a assinatura.

Obviamente, vamos precisar de um certificado digital para realizar a assinatura. Utilizando o CAPICOM, podemos acessar o [Certificate Store do Windows](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2009/07/acessando-o-certificate-store-do.html) e localizar um apropriado, que tenha sido gerado para sua empresa. No entanto, as interfaces disponíveis no MSXML5 exigem que você informe um Certificate Store com o certificado que será utilizado, bem como sua cadeia de validação, se for necessário. Este passo extra é mostrado no quadro abaixo.

```
var store : IStore3;
    cert : TCertificate;
    lKey : IPrivateKey;
begin
    cert := getCert;
    lKey := Cert.PrivateKey;

    { Monta um Store em memória com o Certificado obtido antes }
    store := CoStore.Create;
    store.Open(CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE, 'My', CAPICOM_STORE_OPEN_MAXIMUM_ALLOWED);
    store.Add(cert.DefaultInterface);
    { ... }
```

A função GetCert utilizada acima é minha e segue as instruções descritas no post sobre acesso ao [Certificate Store com CAPICOM](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2009/04/trabalhando-com-o-certificate-store-em.html). De resto, o código apenas cria um Store em memória e adiciona a ele o certificado encontrado. O trecho também salva a chave privada deste certificado, informação que será usada mais adiante para gerar a assinatura em si.

A seguir, precisamos preparar o XML do exemplo para receber a assinatura. É que a interface do MSXML5 responsável por essa etapa se baseia num nó Signature do XML. Esse nó descreve as transformações pelas quais o XML deve ser submetido antes de ser de fato assinado. O nó Signature deve ser criado como mostrado abaixo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<enviNFe versao="2.00" xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe">
   <idLote>71</idLote>
   <NFe>
         { ... }
      <Signature>
         <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
            <Reference URI="#NFe3508059978"
               <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
               </Transforms>
               <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
               <DigestValue></DigestValue>
            </Reference>
         </SignedInfo>
         <SignatureValue><SignatureValue>
      </Signature>
   </NFe>
</enviNFe>
```

Como podemos ver acima, o nó também deixa reservado um local para receber o hash (DigestValue) e outro para a própria assinatura (SignatureValue), que serão preenchidos automaticamente. A única parte variável do bloco preparado acima é o atributo URI da tag Reference, valor que reflete a identificação da Nota Fiscal contida no XML. Ou seja, deve-se montar o valor desse atributo a partir do valor do atributo Id da tag infNFe, precedendo este valor com o sinal #. Como o próprio nome diz, essa parte do XML faz referência ao nó (e seus filhos) que será resguardado pela assinatura digital.

Uma vez que o XML está preparado, podemos partir para a assinatura propriamente dita, o que é conseguido através da interface [IXMLDigitalSignature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756071%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) do MSXML5. Então, precisamos criar uma instância dela e lhe fornecedor os dados para a assinatura:

```
var {...}
      xmlDoc: IXmlDomDocument3;
      noSignature : IXMLDOMElement;
      xmlSign : IXMLDigitalSignature;
      xmlDsigKey: IXMLDSigKey;
begin
      {...}
      { Monta o XML e prepara a tag Signature }
      xmlDoc := PreparaXML ();
      noSignature := EncontraNodeSignature (xmlDoc);

      if (noSignature <> Nil) then begin
      xmlSign := CoMXDigitalSignature50.Create;
      xmlSign.signature := noSignature;
      xmlSign.store := store;

      { Monta a chave com o tipo exigido pelo método Sign }
      xmlDsigKey := xmlSign.createKeyFromCSP(lKey.ProviderType, lKey.ProviderName, lKey.ContainerName, 0);
      { Assina o XML }
      xmlSign.sign(xmlDsigKey, NOKEYINFO);
      {...}
   end;
end;
```

Como podemos ver no trecho de código acima, o IXMLDigitalSignature precisa que indiquemos qual é o nó Signature do nosso XmlDomDocument e o Certificate Store que construímos no início do post. Agora, temos que chamar o método [sign](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms755717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para completar o serviço. Para funcionar, ele precisa de algumas informações baseadas na chave privada do certificado. No exemplo acima, utilizei a chave recuperada a partir do certificado para criar uma instância da interface [IXMLDSigKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms753796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contendo as informações necessárias.

O segundo parâmetro da função sign determina como os dados da chave serão incluídos na estrutura do XML. No exemplo, usei o valor [NOKEYINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms757002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) para que tais dados não sejam incluídos automaticamente.

Após chamar a função sign, as tags que deixamos reservadas no nó Signature são automaticamente calculadas e preenchidas. Finalizando, para que o XML fique no padrão exigido para Notas Fiscais pela Receita Federal, só falta incluir um nó com os dados do certificado usado para assinar. Mostrei como fazer isso no post [Certificado Digital para inclusão no XML com CAPICOM e Delphi](http://balaiotecnologico.blogspot.com.br/2012/05/preparando-o-certificado-digital-para.html).

Comment: Era isso mesmo que você estava procurando?