# Como assinar um PDF digitalmente em C#?

Tags: c#, certificado-digital, assinatura-digital

Preciso assinar digitalmente um **PDF** previamente criado.

Este **PDF** está sendo criado através de um *Web Service* que usa o *Interop* do *Office* para gerar a partir de um Modelo *Office*.

Já tenho acesso ao **Certificado ICP Brasil**, foi comprada através da (*SERASA* ou *SERPRO*) mas não consigo achar uma referência de como fazer isso sem ter que abandonar toda a rotina já existente de criação do **PDF**.

Posts que já verifiquei mas não consegui adaptar eu mesmo:

- [Delphi usando COM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11004/como-assinar-documentos-com-certificado-digital)
- Assinando [*.jar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109254/como-assinar-arquivo-jar-com-certificado-a3) com outro tipo de certificado
- [PHP porém com métodos que até onde sei não tem em .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109254/como-assinar-arquivo-jar-com-certificado-a3) e ao meu entendimento não conseguiria adaptar.
- [Porte de biblioteca não suportado de Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8441991/how-to-build-pdfbox-for-net).
- Via linha de comando [com OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27482664/good-use-of-certificates-to-sign-a-pdf) mas é outra coisa que não tenho experiência.

Resumindo, já tem rotina de geração de **PDF**, só quero assinar. Alguém tem alguma dica? Não tenho experiência nessa parte de segurança da informação.

**[Editado]**

O ideal é não ter que usar biblioteca paga já que está sendo usado o *Office* (pago) para gerar o **PDF**. Tenho acesso ao fonte do gerador de **PDF** caso a alteração tenha que ser lá.

Comment: Você progrediu no assunto? Está usando alguma biblioteca free? Ou outra paga? Qual?

Answer (score 3):

Para esta finalidade você pode usar o [ItextPdf](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/security-itext5/digital-signatures-white-paper). Neste `link` você encontra um exemplo de como assinar e verificar a assinatura de um `PDF`. Este é um exemplo com [Itextsharp](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/14488/e-signing-pdf-documents-with-itextsharp)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda. Infelizmente o `iTextPDF` possui [custo de licença para uso comercial](http://itextpdf.com/pricing) para aplicações que não sejam de código aberto. Estava procurando algo que não fosse aumentar o custo de desenvolvimento e implantação do projeto. Mesmo assim obrigado pelo exemplo.

Comment: e a Itextsharp ?

Comment: a `iTextSharp` é um porte da `iText` feito pela mesmo empresa. Então usa o mesmo sistema de licença. Inclusive se você procura pelo projeto acaba vendo que apontam pra `iText` por ser da mesma empresa.

Comment: é verdade.......

Comment: @VitorCanova o custo de desenvolvimento provavelmente será muito maior que o custo da assinatura. Sempre pese isso ao tomar decisões técnicas desse tipo.